# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs', Next.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import nookies from 'nookies';

import { firebaseAdmin } from "../firebaseAdmin";

import { TChildren } from "../types/app/app.types";

interface Props {
    children: TChildren;
}

export default function ProtectedRoute(props: Props): JSX.Element {
    return <>
        {props.children}
    </>
}

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const cookies = nookies.get(ctx);
    const data = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(cookies.token);
    console.log(data);
    return {
        props: { message: `Your email is .` },
    };
};
```

await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken throws error module not found: can't resolve fs, How to fix this error?

I know that we have different types of runtime environments like edge, browser nodeJs, but based of the docs and examples getServerSide Props runs on nodeJs environment which means that I shouldn't get this kind of error...

Answer (score 1):

Is the 'fs' module available in the environment?

```
npm i fs-extra
```

Then using commonjs:

```js
const fs = require('fs-extra')
```

OR using latest es6 module system:

```js
import fs from 'fs-extra'
```